# Can the existence of geodesics be deduced from properties of the Laplacian?

Tags: sp.spectral-theory, geodesics, micro-local-analysis

As I understand it, the [semiclassical trace formula](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01405172.pdf) in particular relates lengths of geodesics to eigenvalues of the Laplacian.

> Is it possible to prove that every compact Riemannian manifold has a closed geodesic using some property of the Laplacian (or ideas otherwise around the semiclassical trace formula)?

Of course, it is a classical result that geodesics exist, but the only proof I know uses Morse theory on the free loop space of the manifold, plus some algebraic topology to argue that the free loop space has more homology than the original manifold.

Comment: I don't believe this can be done. The properties of the Laplacian are captured by the, say, heat kernel. The heat kernels tells you, how much heat flows from $a$ to $b$ in time $t$. Heat flows along geodesics, so closed geodesics would be seen on the diagonal of the heat kernel. This, however, cannot distinguish between closed geodesics, and geodesics that return to a given point without closing (i.e., they arrive at the wrong angle).

Comment: @Zero, as I understand, per the paper I referred to, at least for generic metrics the length spectrum (lengths of geodesics) and the spectrum of the Laplacian determine each other. So, certainly the Laplacian knows about geodesics. My question is whether we have enough independent knowledge about Laplacians to use this dictionary to conclude that geodesics exist.  (Re. the heat kernel: according to the second page of this http://www-fourier.univ-grenoble-alpes.fr/~ycolver/All-Articles/07a.pdf, for some reason the heat equation knows nothing but the wave and schrodinger equations are better.)

Comment: This appears to be doable, at least for the case of constant curvature. See, e.g. https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01504945 for an overview.